# Upload to real server and recieve blowfish class not found when log in

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I upload all my CakePHP project (version 2.6.5) to the server and after that everything look fine. However I received blowfish class not found when try to log in to my website.

Here they output:

```
Password hasher class "blowfish" was not found.

Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Stack Trace

CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php line 138 → BaseAuthenticate->passwordHasher()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/FormAuthenticate.php line 79 → BaseAuthenticate->_findUser(string, string)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php line 762 → FormAuthenticate->authenticate(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
CORE/Cake/Controller/Component/AuthComponent.php line 607 → AuthComponent->identify(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
APP/Controller/UsersController.php line 86 → AuthComponent->login()
[internal function] → UsersController->login()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(UsersController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(UsersController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Please give me some advise guys!!!

Comment: At a guess you forgot to upload some files because [that message just means what it says](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.8/lib/Cake/Controller/Component/Auth/BaseAuthenticate.php#L171-L173). Please tag the question with exact version of CakePHP you are using.

Comment: @AD7six I mentioned the version in title. I'm pretty sure all the file are uploaded.

Comment: See the linked lines of code, it's only checking if the class exists or not. The only reasons for a class not to exists (in a CakePHP context, where the application isn't fundamentally broken) is the file not existing, having no read permissions or the file not containing the expected class - You should debug with that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wew...Sorry so much for the mistake.
I see that the mistake is in AppController where i init the Auth Component using wrong class name.

```
'Auth' => array
    (
        'loginRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'users',
            'action' => 'dashboard'
        ),
        'logoutRedirect' => array(
            'controller' => 'pages',
            'action' => 'index',
        ),
        'authError'=>'403 Forbidden',
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'passwordHasher' => 'blowfish',
                'scope' => array('activated' => 1)
            )
        )
        //'authorize' => array('Controller') // Added this line
    );
```

just change blowfish to BlowFish
    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish',

And thank @AD7six so much for answer my question.